# Magento: Is it possible to add block into other block on category view without editing catalog.xml

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I have created a custom module which adds an attribute to magento categories and shows this on my category page.

At first, i edited the category/view.phtml template file to directly retrieve my attribute. Works fine, but is not really a proper solution since I had to edit the default template files.

So I created my own layout .phtml file which renders a custom block on a category page. This works great, as long as I use \’content\’ as reference.

```
    <catalog_category_default>
       <reference name=\"content\">        
         <block type=\"categoryreadmore/readmore\" name=\"slim_readmore\">
```

Thing is, this doesn`t do what I need. I need my block to be placed directly under the category description! In catelog.xml if found this for the category view.

```
    <reference name=\"content\">
        <block type=\"catalog/category_view\" name=\"category.products\" template=\"catalog/category/view.phtml\">
            <block type=\"catalog/product_list\" name=\"product_list\" template=\"catalog/product/list.phtml\">
```

So what I need is my block to be placed above \’product_list\’ inside the \’category.products\’ block.

Is this even possible to do without editing the catalog.xml? I want a one-package module without having to edit default templates everytime I install the module.

Thanks in advance!

---

Any ideas?

My assumption is that this is just not possible, which would be a pity

My current code

config.xml:

```
<frontend>
  <layout>
    <updates>
        <readmore>
            <file>readmore.xml</file>
        </readmore>
    </updates>
  </layout>
```

readmore.xml

```
<catalog_category_default>
   <reference name="content">
     <block type="categoryreadmore/readmore" name="slim_readmore" before="product_list" >
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>readmore/readmore.phtml</template></action> 
     </block>
  </reference>
</catalog_category_default>
```

Comment: Have you found your solution ? I'm looking for it too..

Comment: I did get far but never found out how to use it without any editing in template files. Just did not get it working using the answer below. I did get 'read more' working with a custom created module which adds extra fields for each categorie in which text and label can be managed. Let me know if you`re interested in the code.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely! Module's can define their own layout XML files. In your modules `etc/config.xml` file, define what your layout file's name is and that file can contain the updates you would like to make. Place this file in `app/design/frontend/base/default/layout`. Within your new block, you can add the `before` parameter to specify that it will render before the `product_list` block like so: `<block type=\"categoryreadmore/readmore\" name=\"slim_readmore\" before=\"product_list\">`. Magento is smart enough to know to render this block *before* the `product_list` block. Here is the code that can go in your module's `config.xml`:

```
<config>
    <frontend>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <module_identifier>
                    <file>module_layout_file.xml</file>
                </module_identifier>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend> 
</config>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply, but it just won`t work. I have my own layout.xml file now. The block is declared in that file. It shows up, but just nog on the location I want it to. See my answer below for the current code I am using

In catalog.xml is see that the structure of category view is:
- category view.phtml block
      - productlist block

My block has to be precisely between those two. But because the blocks are nested, it is always placed before or after the categoryview.phtml

Comment: Hi, do you have any idea? Would be so much appreciated